# Transparent encryption of HTML5 storage engine(s)

Tags: javascript, html5, cryptography

I am looking for feedback and possible suggestions regarding a piece of JS code that performs transparent symmetric encryption/decryption of user specified data using the HTML5 `localStorage`, `sessionStorage` or depreciated cookie options.

The project can be viewed in its entirety at [here](https://github.com/jas-/secStore.js).

```
/**
 * secStore.js - Encryption enabled browser storage
 *
 * https://www.github.com/jas-/secStore.js
 *
 * Author: Jason Gerfen <jason.gerfen@gmail.com>
 * License: GPL (see LICENSE)
 */
(function(window, undefined) {

  'use strict';

  /**
   * @function secStore
   * @abstract Namespace for saving/retrieving encrypted HTML5 storage engine
   * data
   */
  var secStore = secStore || function() {

    /**
     * @var {Object} defaults
     * @abstract Default set of options for plug-in
     *
     * @param {Boolean} encrypt Optionally encrypt stored data
     * @param {Object} data Data to be setd (JSON objects)
     * @param {String} passphrase Passphrase to use (optional)
     * @param {String} storage Storage mechanism (local, session or cookies)
     */
    var defaults = {
      encrypt: false,
      data: {},
      key: 'secStore.js',
      passphrase: '',
      storage: 'local'
    };

    /**
     * @method setup
     * @scope private
     * @abstract Initial setup routines
     */
    var setup = setup || {

      /**
       * @function set
       * @scope private
       * @abstract Initialization
       *
       * @param {Object} opts Plug-in option object
       */
      init: function(opts) {
        opts.passphrase = (opts.encrypt && opts.passphrase) ?
          opts.passphrase : (opts.encrypt && !opts.passphrase) ?
          crypto.key(opts) : false;
      }
    };

    /**
     * @method storage
     * @scope private
     * @abstract Interface to handle storage options
     */
    var storage = storage || {

      /**
       * @function quota
       * @scope private
       * @abstract Tests specified storage option for current amount of space available.
       *  - Cookies: 4K
       *  - localStorage: 5MB
       *  - sessionStorage: 5MB
       *  - default: 5MB
       *
       * @param {String} t Type of storage specified
       *
       * @returns {Boolean}
       */
      quota: function(storage) {
        var max = /local|session/.test(storage) ? 1024 * 1025 * 5 :
          1024 * 4,
          cur = libs.total(storage),
          total = max - cur;

        if (total <= 0) {
          return false;
        }

        return true;
      },

      /**
       * @function set
       * @scope private
       * @abstract Interface for saving to available storage mechanisms
       *
       * @param {Object} opts Default options
       * @param {Function} cb Callback function
       *
       * @returns {Boolean}
       */
      set: function(opts, cb) {
        var ret = false;

        if (!storage.quota(opts.storage))
          cb('Browser storage quota has been exceeded.');

        opts.data = (opts.encrypt) ?
          sjcl.encrypt(opts.passphrase, storage.fromJSON(opts.data)) :
          storage.fromJSON(opts.data);

        switch (opts.storage) {
          case 'cookie':
            ret = this.cookie.set(opts);
            break;
          case 'local':
            ret = this.local.set(opts);
            break;
          case 'session':
            ret = this.session.set(opts);
            break;
          default:
            ret = this.local.set(opts);
            break;
        }
        if (!ret) {
          cb('Error occured saving data');
        } else {
          cb(null, 'Successfully set data');
        }
      },

      /**
       * @function get
       * @scope private
       * @abstract Interface for retrieving from available storage mechanisms
       *
       * @param {Object} opts Default options
       * @param {Function} cb Callback function
       *
       * @returns {Object}
       */
      get: function(opts, cb) {
        var ret = {};

        switch (opts.storage) {
          case 'cookie':
            ret = this.cookie.get(opts);
            break;
          case 'local':
            ret = this.local.get(opts);
            break;
          case 'session':
            ret = this.session.get(opts);
            break;
          default:
            ret = this.local.get(opts);
            break;
        }

        ret = sjcl.decrypt(opts.passphrase, ret);
        ret = storage.toJSON(ret);

        if (/object/.test(ret)) {
          cb(null, ret);
        } else {
          cb('Error occured retrieving storage data');
        }
      },

      /**
       * @function fromJSON
       * @scope private
       * @abstract Convert to JSON object to string
       *
       * @param {Object|Array|String} obj Object, Array or String to convert to JSON object
       *
       * @returns {String}
       */
      fromJSON: function(obj) {
        return (/object/.test(typeof(obj))) ? JSON.stringify(obj) : obj;
      },

      /**
       * @function toJSON
       * @scope private
       * @abstract Creates JSON object from formatted string
       *
       * @param {String} obj Object to convert to JSON object
       *
       * @returns {Object}
       */
      toJSON: function(obj) {
        return (/string/.test(typeof(obj))) ? JSON.parse(obj) : obj;
      },

      /**
       * @method cookie
       * @scope private
       * @abstract Method for handling setting & retrieving of cookie objects
       */
      cookie: {

        /**
         * @function set
         * @scope private
         * @abstract Handle setting of cookie objects
         *
         * @param {String} key Key to use for cookies
         * @param {String|Object} value String or object to place in cookie
         *
         * @returns {Boolean}
         */
        set: function(key, value) {
          var d = new Date();
          d.setTime(d.getTime() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
          document.cookie = key + '=' + value + ';expires=' + d.toGMTString() +
            ';path=/;domain=' + this.domain();
          return true;
        },

        /**
         * @function get
         * @scope private
         * @abstract Handle retrieval of cookie objects
         *
         * @param {String} key cookie key
         *
         * @returns {String|False}
         */
        get: function(key) {
          var i, x, y, z = document.cookie.split(";");
          for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
            x = z[i].substr(0, z[i].indexOf('='));
            y = z[i].substr(z[i].indexOf('=') + 1);
            x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
            if (x == key) {
              return unescape(y);
            }
          }
          return false;
        },

        /**
         * @function domain
         * @scope private
         * @abstract Provides current domain of client for cookie realm
         *
         * @returns {String}
         */
        domain: function() {
          return location.hostname;
        }
      },

      /**
       * @method local
       * @scope private
       * @abstract Method for handling setting & retrieving of localStorage objects
       */
      local: {

        /**
         * @function set
         * @scope private
         * @abstract Handle setting & retrieving of localStorage objects
         *
         * @param {Object} opts Application defaults
         *
         * @returns {Boolean}
         */
        set: function(opts) {
          try {
            window.localStorage.setItem(opts.key, opts.data);
            return true;
          } catch (e) {
            return false;
          }
        },

        /**
         * @function get
         * @scope private
         * @abstract Handle retrieval of localStorage objects
         *
         * @param {Object} o Application defaults
         *
         * @returns {Object|String|Boolean}
         */
        get: function(opts) {
          return window.localStorage.getItem(opts.key);
        }
      },

      /**
       * @method session
       * @scope private
       * @abstract Method for handling setting & retrieving of sessionStorage objects
       */
      session: {

        /**
         * @function set
         * @scope private
         * @abstract Set session storage objects
         *
         * @param {Object} o Application defaults
         *
         * @returns {Boolean}
         */
        set: function(opts) {
          try {
            window.sessionStorage.setItem(opts.key, opts.data);
            return true;
          } catch (e) {
            return false;
          }
        },

        /**
         * @function get
         * @scope private
         * @abstract Retrieves sessionStorage objects
         *
         * @param {Object} opts Application defaults
         *
         * @returns {Object|String|Boolean}
         */
        get: function(opts) {
          return window.sessionStorage.getItem(opts.key);
        }
      }
    };

    /**
     * @method crypto
     * @scope private
     * @abstract Interface to handle encryption option
     */
    var crypto = crypto || {

      /**
       * @function key
       * @scope private
       * @abstract Prepares key for encryption/decryption routines
       *
       * @returns {String}
       */
      key: function() {
        var pass = crypto.uid(),
          salt = crypto.salt(pass);

        return sjcl.codec.hex.fromBits(sjcl.misc.pbkdf2(pass, salt,
          10000, 256));
      },

      /**
       * @function uid
       * @scope private
       * @abstract Generates a machine identifier
       *
       * @returns {String}
       */
      uid: function() {
        var ret = window.navigator.appName +
          window.navigator.appCodeName +
          window.navigator.product +
          window.navigator.productSub +
          window.navigator.appVersion +
          window.navigator.buildID +
          window.navigator.userAgent +
          window.navigator.language +
          window.navigator.platform +
          window.navigator.oscpu;
        return ret.replace(/\s/, '');
      },

      /**
       * @function salt
       * @scope private
       * @abstract Creates salt from string & iv
       *
       * @param {String} str Machine identification used as salt
       *
       * @returns {String}
       */
      salt: function(str) {
        var rec, ret, hash = [],
          slt = crypto.iv(str);

        hash[0] = sjcl.hash.sha256.hash(str), rec = [], rec = hash[0],
          ret;

        for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
          hash[i] = sjcl.hash.sha256.hash(hash[i - 1].concat(slt));
          ret = rec.concat(hash[i]);
        }
        return JSON.stringify(sjcl.codec.hex.fromBits(ret));
      },

      /**
       * @function iv
       * @scope private
       * @abstract Creates IV based on UID
       *
       * @param {String} str Supplied string
       *
       * @returns {String}
       */
      iv: function(str) {
        return encodeURI(str.replace(/-/gi, '').substring(16, Math.ceil(
          16 * str.length) % str.length));
      }
    };

    /**
     * @method libs
     * @scope private
     * @abstract Miscellaneous helper libraries
     */
    var libs = libs || {

      /**
       * @function total
       * @scope private
       * @abstract Returns size of specified storage
       *
       * @param {String} engine Storage mechanism
       *
       * @returns {Insteger}
       */
      total: function(storage) {
        var current = '',
          engine = window.storage + 'Storage';

        for (var key in engine) {
          if (engine.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            current += engine[key];
          }
        }

        return current ? 3 + ((current.length * 16) / (8 * 1024)) : 0;
      },

      /**
       * @function size
       * @scope private
       * @abstract Perform calculation on objects
       *
       * @param {Object|Array} obj The object/array to calculate
       *
       * @returns {Integer}
       */
      size: function(obj) {
        var n = 0;

        if (/object/.test(typeof(obj))) {
          for (var i in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(obj[i])) n++;
          }
        } else if (/array/.test(typeof(obj))) {
          n = obj.length;
        }
        return n;
      },

      /**
       * @function merge
       * @scope private
       * @abstract Perform preliminary option/default object merge
       *
       * @param {Object} defaults Application defaults
       * @param {Object} obj User supplied object
       *
       * @returns {Object}
       */
      merge: function(defaults, obj) {
        defaults = defaults || {};

        for (var item in defaults) {
          if (defaults.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
            obj[item] = (/object/.test(typeof(defaults[item]))) ?
              this.merge(obj[item], defaults[item]) : defaults[item];
          }
          obj[item] = defaults[item];
        }

        return obj;
      }
    };

    /**
     * @function get
     * @scope public
     * @abstract Retrieves storage engine data
     *
     * @param {Object} obj User supplied options
     * @param {Function} cb User supplied callback function
     */
    secStore.prototype.get = function(obj, cb) {
      cb = cb || obj;

      var opts = libs.merge(obj, defaults);

      setup.init(opts);

      storage.get(opts, cb);
    };

    /**
     * @function set
     * @scope public
     * @abstract Saves data to specified storage engine
     *
     * @param {Object} obj User supplied options
     * @param {Function} cb User supplied callback function
     */
    secStore.prototype.set = function(obj, cb) {
      cb = cb || obj;

      var opts = libs.merge(obj, defaults);

      setup.init(opts);

      storage.set(opts, cb);
    };

  };

  /* secStore.js, do work */
  window.secStore = secStore;

})(window);
```

Comment: I think there's too much commenting, especially with the `@` things. A short description for when the function name and arguments aren't obviously shouting the purpose of the function is fine, but echoing the function name, scope, arguments, and return value is a bit OTT in my view. I'd write most of them as a single line comment with just the abstract.

Comment: I can appreciate that. However for an automated method of creating documentation it comes in very handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a once over:

- Yay, GPL! I love GPL, note that by posting your code here anybody can use this now as not-GPL
- This is the most readable nested ternary I ever saw

  ```
  init: function(opts) {
    opts.passphrase = (opts.encrypt && opts.passphrase) ?
      opts.passphrase : (opts.encrypt && !opts.passphrase) ?
        crypto.key(opts) : false;
  }
  ```

  You could consider this

  ```
  init: function(opts) {
    opts.passphrase = opts.encrypt ? (opts.passphrase || crypto.key(opts)) : false;
  }
  ```
- Considering the craftyness of your other code I was surprised to find this:

  ```
  if (total <= 0) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
  ```

  consider

  ```
  return !(total <= 0); //Or..
  return total > 0;
  ```
- If your switch equals the exact function name like here:

  ```
  switch (opts.storage) {
    case 'cookie':
      ret = this.cookie.set(opts);
      break;
    case 'local':
      ret = this.local.set(opts);
      break;
    case 'session':
      ret = this.session.set(opts);
      break;
    default:
      ret = this.local.set(opts);
      break;
  }
  ```

  You can just simply access the function dynamically

  ```
  ret = this[opt.storage] ? this[opt.storage].set(opts) : this.local.set(opts);
  ```
- `var i, x, y, z = document.cookie.split(";");` <- x,y,z are unfortunate variable names, I am sure they got teased a lot in school
- To name a a machine identifier `uid` is not ideal, usually `uid` is reserved for unique record id's
- I did not review any of the cryptographic code, but at least you depend on a third party library, that is 90% of the work

Comment: Thanks. I always forget about simply calling the variable as a function. Can you point out the sentence within the GPL that would allow that? Is it GPLv3? I am not a legal jargon master so maybe I need to change the license.

Comment: It's in the usage terms of stackexchange.com, as I understand it, all your posted code becomes http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/

Comment: No kidding, well didn't know that prior to posting here. I suppose the version that is here is the licensed as such but those getting it from my project page (and updated versions) are then under the GPL license correct?

Comment: IANAl, but that is indeed my understanding